# RegEx for IP Address with no range limit

Tags: regex, ip-address

I'm looking for a regex that finds IP Addresses with no range limit (i.e. 0-999). This is "simpler" than a regular IP Address regex but I'm learning regex and am stumped on how to essentially end the regex and not match IP Addresses with more than 4 periods or characters before/after it.

This is what I have: `"/\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}(\d{1,3})\b/"`

So, with this regex it will find most IP Addresses but will fail when there is an IP Address like this:

```
1.2.3.4.5
```

Appreciate the help. And it doesn't matter what flavor or regex, just need to know how to not match the case above.

Comment: Use lookarounds, `"/\b(?<!\d\.)(\d{1,3}\.){3}(\d{1,3})\b(?!\.\d)/"`

Answer (score 2):

You may use [**lookarounds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to restrict the context around your expected matches:

```
\b(?<!\d\.)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b(?!\.\d)
  ^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MWIiF8/1)

Here,

- `(?<!\d\.)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a digit + `.`
- `(?!\.\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a `.` + a digit.

To also make sure the octets of 1 to 3 digits are matched, you may add more restriction:

```
\b(?<!\d\.|\d)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b(?!\.?\d)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MWIiF8/3).

Here, `(?<!\d\.|\d)` also fails if there is a digit immediately in front of the current location, and the lookahead is also failing when there is a digit without a dot in front after the expected match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also.

^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$

Comment: This can safely go as a comment.